# Do a reload of mvc/razor partial view with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my project I have rows of modules loaded from Partial views.
So imagine a grid of small squares with information.
There is a popup dialog for all of them, that displays the data of the clicked module.

Currently when I submit a change in the dialog, the javascript reloads the entire page. BUT, this takes a long time, and I need to be able to refresh only the one dialog.

I can imagine to make a separate js function for each type of module, and then pass some data in, so jquery can find the specific module, and then make an ajax get, for the data. But this requires me to do all the data insertion from js always. instead of using razor and MVC's built in awesomeness.

Does anyone know of a way, to call a partial view inside a div?
Also in the future I will need to reload "some" but not all the modules in an interval refresh. So for future proofing purposes:

What im looking for is something like:

```
function reloadElement(row, column, id){
   var target = $("#div1");
   // todo find row and column
   target.html.partial("url", model); //<----- looking for something like this. cross fingers.
}
```

Comment: if youre reloading data in a div on timed intervals, you can set up a timer in js that will execute an ajax call to your server. the ajax call would hit a controller action which could return either only the new data your view needs in json or can return an entire partial view that you replace on the page

Comment: @GregH "return an entire partial view that you replace on the page", that sounds like what Im looking for.. Can you please make an answer for this question, with a code example of how that would look?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GregH for a few key words, that lead to some ideas.

I solved it myself, so if you land on this problem also, here is how i solved it:

1. Controller:

You want to make your controller `return PartialView("somePartialViewUrl", new SomeModel())`, apparently saving the model and relying on the data collection isn't good enough, i hadto make a new instance of the model.

2. Javascript

in the "click" that handles the event, put:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "controllerName/actionName",
    data: JSON.stringify({ row:1,column:2 .... }),
    contentType: "application/json", 
    dataType: "html", 
    type: "POST",
    success: function (partial) {
        $("#div2").html(partial);
    }
});
```

this will override the html in your "#div2".

im sure you can also use `$("#div2").innerHTML = partial;` or `$("#div2").load("url",parameters);` and probably many other ways.

done.